# Mircrosoft - first last (organization) naming to avoid send errors

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, exchange-server, microsoft-teams

More and more common in organisations is to use "first last (organization)" naming conventions in teams/outlook etc. to avoid sending email to the wrong person with autocomplete.

My problem is how to do this, in AD, in outlook, in 365, in exchange?

Pls help

Best
/Peter

Answer (score 0):

I solved this today. In Azure AD I changed users name from "first last" to "first last (organization)"  It seems to work.

Best/Peter